# How to use single css class for multiple IDs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqwidget

I am trying to apply the following CSS to multiple divs under a given div ID.

```
.strikeout
{
    background : blue;
}
```

I am using the following javascript code to change the color of the selected row in the grid,

```
$("#jqxGridInvoiceEntry").on("cellvaluechanged", function (event){
    var rowindex = event.args.rowindex;
    var checkboxState=event.args.value;
    var rowTag=$("#row"+rowindex+"jqxGridInvoiceEntry div");

    if(checkboxState==true)
    {
        rowTag.addClass("strikeout");
    }
    else
    if(checkboxState==false)
    {
        rowTag.removeClass("strikeout");
    }
});
```

See the screeshot below. When I select the checkbox in first row, its background color changes to blue. The problem is when I select the checkbox in second row, its background color changes blue but the previously selected row's background color disappears. The first row ID will be row0jqxGridInvoiceEntry and so on for subsequent rows.

[image]

I am using JQWidgets framework. The HTML code is,

```
<div style="float: left;" id="jqxGridInvoiceEntry"></div>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: Can you show an example of the relevant HTML?

Comment: Selected row background color is green in picture. Headers is blue... So you want to change header background color?!?

Comment: @panther : I am using a framework called JQWidgets. I will generate the HTML based on the ID is use.

Comment: @Justinas:The green color is due to mouse hover. When I click the checkbox in void column, the entire row should become blue.

Comment: @Max_dev: it doesn't matter how you build your HTML. Take generated HTML and send us link to fiddle. Now we are speakin about unknown HTML, we don't know where is the problem.

Comment: @Max_dev can you please give feedback on the answers here?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester I abondoned the jqwidgets framework. There is no solution to this problem as of now...

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility, judging from the code you posted, is that the `cellvaluechanged` event also fires for the first row, perhaps because the checkbox in it is unchecked when you check the other checkbox in row 2.

This code:

```
else
if(checkboxState==false)
{
    rowTag.removeClass("strikeout");
}
```

will remove the background color.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way jquery implemented is little confusing. Here I am coming with different way of implementing the same result.

**HTML**

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" id="MainTable">
<tr>
    <td>First</td> 
    <td><input type='checkbox'  /></td>
    <td>Some INformation</td>
    <td>Testing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Second</td> 
    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
    <td>Some INformation</td>
    <td>Testing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Third</td> 
    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
    <td>Some INformation</td>
    <td>Testing</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
 table
 {
 border-top:1px solid #000;
 border-right:1px solid #000;
 }
 table td
 {
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
 border-left:1px solid #000;
 }
 .green
{
  background-color:green;
 }
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $('#MainTable input[type=checkbox]').on('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('green').siblings().toggleClass('green');
  });
```

[**Working JSFIDDLE Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XN8ZN/1/)

Answer (score -1):

look to me like, your page is kind of reloaded when your callback is over.

if found [this](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). they say you should use preventDefault() to forbid this behavior. hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

> .strikeout .otherdivClass .thirdCssClass {
>       background : blue; }